# NHibernate - Select Random Number of Records with LINQ

Tags: linq, nhibernate, random, linq-to-nhibernate

Does anyone know how to select a random number of records in NHibernate using LINQ.

I hoped I could say something like:

```
var rand = new Random();
var test = session.Query<Entity>().OrderBy(x => rand.Next()).Take(5).ToList();
```

However it doesn't like variables in the OrderBy expression. One option is to call ToList before I do the ordering but this grabs the whole record set which is not ideal as it could return thousands of records.

I've also discovered the following (scroll down to the bottom answer):

[NHibernate Insert into ... select ... with GUID as PrimaryKey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528914/nhibernate-insert-into-select-with-guid-as-primarykey/13464397)

However I'm not sure how I would call this using LINQ. I'd appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're selecting a random number of records... rather, you're selecting 5 randomly ordered records. Could you please add some further explanation?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've updated the title as it was abit misleading. To select a random  number of records with MS SQL Server you order by NEWID() and do a top. e.g. "SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Products ORDER BY NEWID()". I'm trying to write the LINQ equivalent.

Comment: This type of query could be problematic for performance if there are lots of rows in the `Entity` table.  Even if you're just fetching 5 records, SQL Server would still have to do a table scan, evaluating `NEWID()` for every row in the table.

Comment: There's also the `RAND()` function - I don't know which would have better performance, or whether `RAND`s results would be more randomly distributed than `NEWID`.

Comment: I'm currently thinking you would have to find a way to extend the NHibernate LINQ provider - along the same lines as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916122/nhibernate-3-extending-linq-provider-basehqlgeneratorformethod-buildhql-proble

Comment: Why do you have to use LINQ?  Since this seems to be easily answered using `QueryOver`, why can't you use that?

Comment: @DanielSchilling: I'd like to switch out NHibernate to Entity framework easily by building a wrapper around it.

Comment: It's likely that you'll have this same problem with Entity Framework, too (haven't checked - just my bet).  The job of the LINQ provider, whether it is NHibernate or Entity Framework, is to translate .NET expressions into SQL queries.  In order to be able to handle this type of query, the LINQ Provider would have had to be explicitly instructed to translate `System.Random.Next()` into `RAND()`.  I suppose it's possible that Microsoft had the foresight to do this, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: I encourage you to read [Ayende's post about abstracting away your O/RM like this](http://ayende.com/blog/4567/the-false-myth-of-encapsulating-data-access-in-the-dal).  In addition to the points he lists there, I'd like to add: You Aren't Going To Need It.  Just pick the best one, NHibernate, and go with it. ;) Adding a layer in between you and your ORM increases complexity and reduces the power of your ORM, for what will likely end up being zero benefit.

Comment: I disagree. I have written a series of Unit Tests which executes a bunch of LINQ expressions using both NHibernate and Entity Framework. This way I can switch out to Entity Framework in the future once it passes all of my tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution is probably not very good because it changes the shape of your entities, but if that's acceptable for your use case...

Based on this post by Ayende it looks like it's pretty easy to map SQL functions to properties on your entities:

http://ayende.com/blog/1720/using-sql-functions-in-nhibernate

Could you add a property mapping like

`<property name='Random' formula='NEWID()'/>`

for the entity you are targeting? Then you should be able to write a query like

`var test = session.Query<Entity>().OrderBy(x => x.Random).Take(5).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks this looks promising. I will test this tomorrow and let you know my findings.

Comment: NEWID() works in SQL Server but not SQL Lite - is there anyway of doing conditional mapping depending on the target database? We use SQL Lite for unit tests - Random() works there

Answer (score 1):

To do this with NHibernate you need to add the following class ...

```
public class RandomOrder : Order
{
   public RandomOrder()
      : base(String.Empty, true)
   { }

   public override SqlString ToSqlString(ICriteria criteria, ICriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
   {
      return new SqlString("NEWID()");
   }
}
```

And the following extension method ...

```
public static IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> OrderByRandom<TRoot, TSubType>(this IQueryOver<TRoot, TSubType> query)
{
   query.UnderlyingCriteria.AddOrder(new RandomOrder());

   return query;
}
```

This will allow you to do the following ...

`var test = session.QueryOver<Entity>().OrderByRandom().Take(5).ToList();`

---

To do this with NHibernate FluentMapping and Linq to NHibernate ...

Add a new property to your class

`public virtual string Random { get; set; }`

Then add the flowing mapping to your `ClassMap<T>`

`Map(o => o.Random).Formula("NEWID()");`

Finally you can call it via the following

`ctx.Query<T>().OrderBy(o => o.Random).Take(5).ToList();`

---

And to do this with EF you need to add the following method to your DataContext class ...

```
[Function(Name = "NEWID", IsComposable = true)]
[return: Parameter(DbType = "uniqueidentifier")]
public Guid Random()
{
   return Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

then you can call it by doing the following ...

```
dc.Products.OrderBy(o => dc.Random()).Take(5)
```

which will give you the following results ...

```
SELECT TOP(5) * FROM Products ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Comment: @Zote Opps just noticed that, added an NHibernate version as well :)

Comment: Surely this solution is for QueryOver and not LINQ?

Comment: +1 for adding the NH answer.  I never thought of inheriting from `Order` before.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the one you are looking for,

http://puredotnetcoder.blogspot.com/2011/09/nhibernate-queryover-and-newid-or-rand.html

Comment: Thanks but again this is for QueryOver and not LINQ IQueryable.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a way to call custom sql function in LINQ IQueryable:

```
internal static class CustomLinqExtensions
{
    [LinqExtensionMethod]
    public static string Random2(this int input)
    {
        // source: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html
        throw new NotImplementedException("This call should be translated to SQL and run db side, but it has run with .Net runtime");
    }
}
```

Then you have to create custom SQL Function called Random2. For example in PostgreSQL it will be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RANDOM2(in INTEGER) RETURNS DOUBLE PRECISION AS
$$
BEGIN
  RETURN random();
END;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And finally you can call it in OrderBy LINQ extension

```
var query = CurrentSession.Query<SampleClass>()
   .OrderBy(x => x.Id.Random2());
```

As a result the following sql query is going to be generated:

```
SELECT ... FROM Sample s order by Random2(s.Id) asc;
```